# SQL IF EXISTS ignores errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

This query:

```
SELECT 3/0 AS X
```

returns an error, as expected:

> Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Divide by zero error encountered.

But `IF EXISTS` treats X as a row that exists. This query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 3/0 AS X) 
    PRINT 'SUCCESS'
ELSE 
    PRINT 'FAILURE'
```

returns 'SUCCESS'. I couldn't find anything in the IF EXISTS documentation that explains this behavior. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not exactly "ignore" errors specifically.  It is ignoring everything in the `select` clause (with the exception of `top (0)`).

`exists` is checking to see if any *rows* are returned by the query.  As an optimization, it ignores the `select` part of the query, because this does not affect the existence of rows.

Incidentally, you get the same effect with `case`:

```
select (case when 1=1 then 1 else 1/0 end)
```

also returns 1 rather than an error.

Answer (score 3):

The expression in the `SELECT` statement does not need to be evaluated in order for SQL Server to process the EXISTS predicate. Look at the execution plan to see what the optimizer does with this query:

[image: IF EXISTS Plan]

Note the `VALUES` returned by the scalar operator are not those that were specified in the `SELECT` clause. No error occurs because the actual expression used in the query does not divide by zero.